# Is len(text.split()) faster than text.count(" ")? And why so? python

Tags: python, string, count, text-files, string-length

Given that I have 1,000,000,000 lines of ~20-100 tokens per line delimited by whitespace, counting the length of each line becomes sort of non-trival.

Assuming that there are never double whitespaces between two tokens,

1. Is `len(text.split())` faster than `text.count(" ")+1`?
2. And why so?

Comment: Why don't you profile it?

Comment: `len()` will have to wait for `split()` to traverse through the string and split it up. `count` and `split` will there for be equally fast because they both have to walk through the string and do operations. but adding `len()` will be one extra step and slow things down. Also: `import time; started = time(); len(text.split()); print(time() - started);` to get the time.

Comment: Those are both different operations and will not yield the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to check which is faster:

```
>python -m timeit -s "s='q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l'" "s.count(' ')+1"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.272 usec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "s='q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l'" "len(s.split())"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.653 usec per loop
```

`split` is slower, probably because it constructs the splitted list.

Comment: i think you need to +1 because `len(x.split()) == x.count(' ')+1`

Answer (score 2):

`text.count(" ")` is wrong, see below:

```
In [706]: t='a  b    c'

In [707]: t.split()
Out[707]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [708]: t.count(' ')
Out[708]: 6
```

You don't wanna get 6 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is incorrect. Both of those operations do not give the same results, lets use your question as an example:

```
>>> text = "Given that I have 1,000,000,000 lines of ~20-100 tokens per line delimited by whitespace, counting the length of each line becomes sort of non-trival."
>>> len(text.split())
24
>>> text.count(" ")
23
```

Given your question of "counting the length of each line" neither of those operations even do that.

To count each line you need to do:

```
line_lengths = [len(line) for line in text.splitlines()]
```

But it would probably be better to also note the line number:

```
line_lengths = [(idx, len(line)) for idx, line in enumerate(text.splitlines())]
```